# Creating an area plot from a table

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, datatable, area

I created a table in R using cross_rpct. I am sharing the code I used for creating the table below

```r
library(expss)
libaray(ggplot2)

table_temp <-  KRiycf %>% 
  filter(nt_bf_curr==1) %>%
  cross_rpct(
    cell_vars = list(agecats,total()),
    col_vars = list(nt_formula, nt_milk, nt_juice,nt_soup_broth,nt_other_liq, nt_bbyfood, nt_bread_noodles,nt_vege,nt_dark_green_vege, 
                    nt_fruits, nt_other_fruits, nt_root,nt_meat,nt_organs,nt_fish, nt_nuts,nt_eggs, nt_dairy, nt_solids),
    weight = wt,
    total_label = "Weighted N",
    total_statistic = "w_cases",
    total_row_position = c("below"),
    expss_digits(digits=1)) %>%
  set_caption("Food and liquids consumed - bf children")
```

From the table I created I want plot an area plot, where I can have percentages on the y axis and age groups in x axis. I am sharing a small snippet of my dataset below, I have updated the dataset here:

```r
structure(list(row_labels = c("|0-1", "2-3", "4-5", "|6-8"), `Child given infant formula in day/night before survey - last-born under 2 years|No` = c(97.9075507494789, 
97.8041295975246, 94.6578401315905, 95.041187412934), `Child given infant formula in day/night before survey - last-born under 2 years|Yes` = c(2.09244925052114, 
2.19587040247545, 5.34215986840951, 4.95881258706603), `Child given other milk in day/night before survey- last-born under 2 years|No` = c(98.6895801515596, 
97.4560395412179, 95.074878916869, 91.6660752233646)), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = c("etable", "with_caption", "data.frame"))
```

I am attaching a sample of what kind of graph I want.

[image]

I tried converting data into long format and then using ggplot, but this did not work.

```r
long<-table_temp%>%pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("row"), names_to = "Age categories", values_to = "Perctanges")

ggplot(long, aes(x = `Age categories`, y = Percentage, fill = row)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  labs(title = "Food Consumption by Category",
       x = "Category",
       y = "Percentage") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: You might want `geom_area()`.

Comment: Provide a sample data for Your example. Use `library` explicitly in Your code to show what packages You use, where the function `cross_rpct` comes from. As mentioned in a comment - follow the rules of including a reproducible example.

Comment: I changed the question with sample data and libraries.

Comment: @Mahir Perhaps you want a [stacked area plot](https://r-graph-gallery.com/136-stacked-area-chart.html)?

Comment: @Ben Thanks, this is what I was looking for.  :)